# replacing multiple threads writing to outputstream with one writer thread (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an existing app where multiple threads are writing via an outputstream (and synchronizing on it).  I am wondering whether switching over to a single writer principle for writing to the outputstream might be more efficient (I am just doing this for academic reasons as I do not believe this will impact the app performance that much though I could be wrong).  For now, I am only thinking of using a blockingqueue or a ring buffer for all current writers to write to and one writer thread (consumer for the queue/ringbuffer) to write to the output stream/channel.
Any thoughts on this or helpful suggestions would be quite welcome.

Comment: What, specifically, is your question?  It is difficult to tell.

Comment: It you are talking about writing to single file than every write will have to involve THREE operations - <sync>OPEN, APPEND, (FLUSH,) CLOSE</sync> With growing number of threads competing to do that it WILL start to impact performance. My approach to these situations is to use (multiple) producers -> single consumer approach - using data/message queue or similar. Depending on queue implementation you may not need ANY syncing at all thus eliminating any waiting and dead-locks

Comment: @Germann - that's the idea I am exploring

Comment: @Germann - the output is to a socket client.

Comment: May be I don't understand something: why do you need/want too synchronize on socket output? Is not it a separate socket per thread? In which case synchronization is irrelevant.

Comment: @Germann - sorry for the confusion.  The synchronization is on the OutputStream.  The app written by another developer is currently using blocking IO (and I'm looking to change it).  Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enough free capacity on your system (idle CPU time, available IO time) then adding a separate thread to do the logging IO only will noticeably improve the performance of the overall system.

Adding a Queue from the `java.util.concurrent` package with a bunch of threads that add to the queue, and a logging thread that reads from the queue and writes out the output will be a good solution.

On the other hand, if you have a fully utilized system then the queue will either become too large, or the overhead will become noticable, and the benefits of the logging thread will become negligible.

In most cases I have seen a seperate logging thread is beneficial.

Comment: thanks - that's the idea I am looking into.  I was thinking of mixing it with the disruptor pattern with multiple producers - if that does not work, I'll flip over to an arrayblockingqueue/linkedblockingqueue.

Comment: fyi its not to log output but to actually write to a socket client.